# Bootstrap ZeroCurve with only one ex-div date and one div amount

Tags: c++, quantlib

This is probably a really dumb question, but not sure what to do. I have a function that returns **all** the ex div dates and the divYield corresponding at that `evalDate` **to** `expiration` date of the option.

```
Handle<YieldTermStructure> dividendTermStructure(bootstrapDividendCurveDB("INTC", today, expiration, underlyingPrice));

boost::shared_ptr<ZeroCurve> 
bootstrapDividendCurveDB()
{
....
    return boost::shared_ptr<ZeroCurve>(new ZeroCurve(ddy.exDivDates, ddy.dividendYields, ActualActual(), calendar));
}
```

This then gets passed to

```
//instantiate BSM process
    Handle<Quote> underlyingH(boost::shared_ptr<Quote>(new SimpleQuote(underlyingPrice)));
    boost::shared_ptr<BlackScholesMertonProcess> bsmProcess(new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, 
        dividendTermStructure, yieldTermStructure, volatilityTermStructure));
```

However, if there is only one dividend in between `evalDate` and `expiration`, and therefore `ddy.exDivDates`, `ddy.dividendYields` each only contain one entry, I get an error:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error: in "testAmericanOptionPricingWithDividends": QuantLib::Error: not enough input dates given
FD_Div_IRAmerican.cpp(524): last checkpoint: "testAmericanOptionPricingWithDividends" entry.
```

The way the example that I got this section of code from solves this is by taking the previous dividend yield even though the evalDate (today) is past that ex-div date. That way there is at least two values from which there are enough points to build a `ZeroCurve`.

That doesn't seem correct. What to do in this case for short dated options that may have only one dividend in between expiry and "today"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it might make sense to use a flat curve based on the single value you have.  Your factory function will be something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> 
bootstrapDividendCurveDB()
{
...
if (just one dividend)
    return boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(evalDate, single_dividend,
                                           ActualActual());
else
    return boost::make_shared<ZeroCurve>(ddy.exDivDates, ddy.dividendYields,
                                         ActualActual(), calendar));
}
```

A note: if you build it as above, the reference date for the `ZeroCurve` will be the first date in the `exDivDate` vector, not the evaluation date.  If that's not what you wanted, you'll have to add the evaluation date in front of the date vector and another dividend (possibly a copy of the first one) in front of the rate vector.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I am a bit confused by your "A note". Are you saying that what I return should not be the ex-div date, but the eval date (today) ? I guess I am not sure why the caution is warranted?

Comment: I mean that the curve starts at the first date in the `ddy.exDivDates` vector and will raise an exception if asked for a rate before that date.